# Convert Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to convert my postcodes and towns in an array of JSON objects, but I guess I'm not doing it right, I need it for my autocomplete functionality.

Here is my code:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM uk_postcodes";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $dname_list = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      //  [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, { label: "Choice2", value: "value2" } ]

       $dname_list[] = "{label:".$row['postcode'].","."value:".$row['town']."}";
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($dname_list);
```

Comment: `$dname_list[] = array('label'=>$row['postcode'], 'value'=>$row['town']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to insert json with strings. You can rely entirely on json_encode.

This is how i would do

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM uk_postcodes";
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

 $dname_list = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $dname_list[] = array(
       "label" => $row['postcode'],
       "value" => $row['town']
    );
 }
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($dname_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make each entry in your object an array.  This should work:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     $matches[] = array(
                'label'=> $row["postcode"],
                'value'=> $row["town"],
                    );
}
```